# How to use the full textwidth for tablenotes under multiple subtables?

Tags: tables, subfloats, booktabs, tablenotes

When i use subtables and want to include one tablenote which describes all tables simultaneously the tablenote is only created for the left table not using the whole textwidth. How can i make a tablenote making use of the whole text width?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \caption{test}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{subtable}{0.426\linewidth}
            \caption{test1}
            \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
            \begin{tabular} l
                \toprule
                test \\
                \midrule 
                1 \\
                \bottomrule 
            \end{tabular}
        \end{subtable}
        \begin{subtable}{0.282\linewidth}
            \caption{test2}
            \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
            \begin{tabular} l
                \toprule
                test \\
                \midrule
                2 \\
                \bottomrule 
            \end{tabular}
        \end{subtable}
        \begin{subtable}{0.282\linewidth}
            \caption{test3}
            \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
            \begin{tabular} l
                \toprule
                test \\
                \midrule 
                3 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{subtable} 
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item{\textit{Notes:}} test test test test test test test test test test test test 
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the measurement of threeparttable:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{a4wide} %better use geometry.
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \caption{test}
    \begin{threeparttable}    
        \begin{subtable}{0.426\linewidth}
            \caption{test1}
            \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
            \begin{tabular} l
                \toprule
                test \\
                \midrule
                1 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{subtable}
        \begin{subtable}{0.282\linewidth}
            \caption{test2}
            \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
            \begin{tabular} l
                \toprule
                test \\
                \midrule
                2 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{subtable}
        \begin{subtable}{0.282\linewidth}
            \caption{test3}
            \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
            \begin{tabular} l
                \toprule
                test \\
                \midrule
                3 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{subtable}

        \makeatletter\def\TPT@hsize{}\makeatletter

        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item{\textit{Notes:}} test test test test test test test test test test test test
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```